# JQuery - $this is not defined

Tags: jquery

Trying to get this code to work but the error I am getting in firebug is `$this is not defined` and I don't understand why

To explain the background about this code I have a list of spans with identical classes so when I click on particular span I need to send an ajax request and update that particular span.

Hopefully that makes sense.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function postAndFade($node, post_key) {
    var id = $node.parents('.id').find('.id-value').text();
    var post_val = $node.text();
    $node.fadeOut('slow');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: "id="+id+"&"+post_key+"="+post_val,
        success: function(data) {
           $node.html(data);
           $node.fadeIn('slow');        
        }
    });
return false;
}
$('.featured-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($this, 'featured'); });
$('.visible-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($this, 'visible'); });
});
```

Comment: I don't speak jquery, but does it really have something called '$this'? Perhaps you mean 'this' or '$(this)'?

Comment: are you sure this is the block of code causing the error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it's not - you're looking for `$(this)`.

Fuller explanation - jQuery sets the context of event handlers by setting the value of `this` to the element triggering the event. In order to reference this in jQuery, you need to wrap it in a jQuery call, like this: `$(this)`. Because you often need to do lots of stuff with that element, it's a common coding pattern to assign it to a variable called `$this`:

```
$(el).click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // now do stuff with $this
});
```

But that's a convention, not something jQuery does for you.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaah. Thank you very much. Another painful lesson learned.

Answer (score 6):

use this code

```
$(this) instead of $this
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `$(this)`, not `$this`.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
$('.featured-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($(this), 'featured'); });
$('.visible-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($(this), 'visible'); });
```

`this` is a reference to the DOM element.

`$this` isn't anything, it is sometimes used like so: `var $this = $(this)` in order to save the jQuery object, so you aren't recreating it multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use $(this) instead of $this

```
$('.featured-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($(this), 'featured'); });
$('.visible-value').click(function() { return postAndFade($(this), 'visible'); });
```